# The expectation including an indicator function

Tags: exponential-function, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

I stumbled upon this homework question and I simply cannot wrap my head around it:

[image]

As far as I understood it, I would start off with the following:
[image]

But I get completely stuck from here on out. Perhaps my first move is already wrong. Could anyone please help?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You have one too many integral signs.  There should be one per $d$.  The rest is calculus.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should begin with

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{mx} I_{X \leq d} f(x) dx$

where $I$ is the indicator, $f$ is the density function. This then becomes

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^d e^{mx} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2} dx$

The main trick you'll want to use is $e^{mx} e^{-x^2 / 2} = e^{-x^2/2 + mx}$. Then, you'll want to complete the square.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the correct answer! I greatly appreciate the effort!

Comment: @MathNoob123 You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.